# AWS Amplify, "Error: No credentials" when getting items from AppSync graphql API

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I've published my React application to amplify, everything went fine there. But when I open the amplify URL I see that no items have been fetched from database and I have an error in console saying "No credentials"

I think the problem lies with the AppSync API somehow.
I made it using the Amplify CLI, it uses API key authentication.

Locally I provide credentials using the generated file `aws-exports.js`. I Import this in my `index.tsx` like so:

```
import awsmobile from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But this file is not pushed to git, so Amplify obviously doesn't have this from the repo. But I assumed that it was able to generate its own `aws-exports.js` file, as it doesn't give any errors on the import.

So, what am I missing here? Do I have to use another method for authentication on my AppSync api or what is wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have found the solution.

I simply had to annotate my schema.graphql with `@aws_api_key` like so:

```
type Item @model @aws_api_key {
  id: ID!
  name: String
}
```

and of course any custom mutations and subscriptions you have defined aswell.

See: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/graphql-security-appsync-amplify/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add auth rules in your schema.graphql as below

`type Item @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) { id: ID! name: String }`

PS: This will allow public access to all crud operations, you can customize as you want